# Django putting logic in view vs serializer vs model best approach

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

What is the best approach about putting logic and what is best in my current scenario where I have a view which uses a query + subquery to fetch and return data.

```
@action(detail=False, methods=["get"], url_name="inventory")
def inventory(
    self, request: Request, *args: None, **kwargs: None
) -> Response:

    required = (
        ProductionJob.objects.filter(item=OuterRef("pk"))
        .order_by()
        .filter(status="Pending")
        .values("item")
        .annotate(
            amount_sum=Sum(
                "required_item", output_field=FloatField()
            )
        )
        .values("amount_sum")
    )

    data = (
        Item.objects.select_related("supplier")
        .prefetch_related("item_jobs")
        .annotate(
            item_required=Coalesce(
                Subquery(required),
                0,
                output_field=FloatField(),
            )
        )
        .values(
            "id",
            "article_id",
            "composition",
            "width_meter",
            required_for_jobs=Sum("item_required"),
            supplier_name=F("supplier__name"),
        )
    )
    return Response(data=data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

The question is what is the best place to keep this code. It can be put on a model's QuerySet or if it should be moved to serializer then how?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you use a serializer here?

Comment: Don't have a serializer in this scenario and don't know how to use one.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you don't have have comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code to the serializer this way.
Here is the view:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=["get"], url_name="inventory")
def inventory(self, request: Request, *args: None, **kwargs: None) -> Response:
    queryset = Item.objects.select_related("supplier").prefetch_related(
        "item_jobs"
    )
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

And the serializer:

```
class ItemInventorySerializer(ModelSerializer[Item]):
    supplier_name = SerializerMethodField(required=False)
    required_for_jobs = SerializerMethodField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = [
            "id",
            "article_id",
            "composition",
            "width_meter",
            "required_for_jobs",
            "supplier_name",
        ]

    def get_supplier_name(self, obj: Item) -> str:
        return obj.supplier.name

    def get_required_for_jobs(self, obj: Item) -> Optional[float]:
        return obj.item_jobs.aggregate(
            required_for_jobs=Coalesce(
                Sum("required_item_meters"), 0, output_field=FloatField()
            )
        ).get("required_for_jobs")
```

The question still remains that what is the better approach. Keeping this in the view or the serializer.
Thank you.